# How to migrate Oracle 11g on-premise database to Oracle 18c cloud?

Tags: oracle11g, database-migration, oracle18c

As per my knowledge, Oracle 18c can be installed as on-premise database. But what is actually cloud database? Is it that we download and install 18c on any AWS kind of cloud platform or is it that 18c directly offers database as a service, where we have to just use the connection strings to connect to the database??
Please explain this layman question

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable for the question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll add the question in that.

Comment: I've added it in https://dba.stackexchange.com Here is the link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238565/how-to-migrate-oracle-11g-on-premise-database-to-oracle-18c-cloud